# Highstocks rangeSelector input with global useUTC: false doesn't work

Tags: javascript, date, highcharts

As the title suggests, I have trouble with the rangeSelector input when setting the global useUTC option to false, i.e. the following setting:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

I have two fiddles for demostrating this issue.

### Fiddle 1 - Date & hour formatting (works)

[Fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/koffertfisk/ojx5hkoa/1/) uses date & time as date formatting option, i.e.

```
inputDateFormat: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
inputEditDateFormat: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

which is working fine. If you, for example, choose `2010-09-22 00:00:00` as input, it will output `From: 2010-09-22 00:00:00+02:00` (since I'm in GMT+2).

### Fiddle 2 - Only date formatting (does not work)

[Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/koffertfisk/tq7q8gxs/1/) uses only the date as date formatting option, i.e.

```
inputDateFormat: "%Y-%m-%d",
inputEditDateFormat: "%Y-%m-%d"
```

Choosing `2010-09-22` in this example should produce the same output as the example in **Fiddle 1** but outputs `From: 2010-09-22 02:00:00+02:00`. I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I suppose writing a custom fallback function for the date parsing would be an option but my guess is that I'm missing something else here.

---

### Update 1

Based on this [this github topic](http://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/433) (mentioned in the comments), I wrote this custom inputDateParser function:

```
inputDateParser: function (value) {
    var temp_date;
    if (defaultOptions.global.useUTC) {
        temp_date = moment.utc(value);
    }
    else {
        temp_date = moment(value);
    }
        return temp_date.valueOf();
}
```

(..which requires storing the global options into a variable)

```
var defaultOptions = Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koffertfisk/tq7q8gxs/2/)

Comment: Take a look at this topic: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/433.

Comment: @d_paul: This got me on the right track, updated the OP. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem, glad it helped.